# overlay multiple images on a video with specific time per image and repeat (loop) the process the images until video end

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg, overlay

I am trying to making video with ffmpeg where I want to overlay images on a video.
I want to show the image for 5 secound each and want to the process to loop until the video end.
I am using following commend which working perfectly but want to modify to loop the images.

```
ffmpeg -y -i long_process/2-scrolling.mp4 \
-i upload-images/040820221255452.png \
-i upload-images/040820221255453.png \
-filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=75:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t, 1, 5)'[v0]; \
[v0][2:v]overlay=75:(H-h)/2:enable='between(t, 5, 10)'" \
-c:a copy long_process/output.mp4
```

I am very new to ffmpeg looking for help from you.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer

```
ffmpeg -y -i long_process/2-scrolling.mp4 -framerate 1/3 -pattern_type glob -loop 1 -i 'tools/*.png' \
-filter_complex "[0]overlay=75:(H-h)/2:shortest=1" \
-r 60  -c:a copy long_process/output.mp4
```